# SSRS Reporting services Rest API Unauthorized

Tags: c#, rest, api, reporting-services

I'm trying to get a list of reports from SSRS Rest API. I can see them when I navigate to the URL `http://someaddress/reports/api/V2.0/reports` in chrome

When I navigate there in the browser an input box shows up and asks for a username and password.

So I've tried this:

```
  var client = new HttpClient(){BaseAddress= new Uri("Http://someaddress/reports/api/V2.0");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Username",@"someuser");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Password",@"some password");
  var response= await _client.GetAsync("reports");
```

It's returning 401 unauthorized.

Can someone please explain how I can pass the username and password in so I get the correct response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using username and password, you need to use NTLM cretendials to authenticate the request. You can achieve it using `HttpClientHandler` and `CredentialCache`, like this:

```cs
 var uri = new Uri("Http://someaddress/reports/api/V2.0");
 var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(@"someuser", @"some password", "");

 var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache { { uri, "NTLM", networkCredential } };
 var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialsCache };

 var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = uri };
 var response= await client.GetAsync("reports");
```